# Vue sortable not working properly

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working with [vue-sortable and dragable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) and at the moment I can drag a item above and change its position, but my json doesn't get refreshed, so I have this list:

```
<draggable v-model="this.$store.getters.getDocument.getDocumentAttributes">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" v-for="(value, key, index) in this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes">
        <div class="panel-body quote">
            <span @click="removeSection(index,key)" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-info"></span>
            <p>{{value.key}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</draggable>
```

I get the list from vuex store, I can swap the elements but the json doesn't refresh, how can I do it?

Comment: What JSON? There's no JSON in your code.

Comment: there is no json in my code, but to play with this thing you need json

Comment: Umh ... to play with this post we need more code. Questions here should stand on their own content, external links are some extra only. It is also highly unlikely, that vue would organize a string automatically ..?

Comment: won't discuss with you, but doesn't make sense, my json data will be load dynamicly the v-for just add a row at each iteration using the json data my problem is not with the json directly since it loads, but with the sortable

Answer (score 0):

Your v-model is `this.$store.getters.getDocument.getDocumentAttributes`. It's vuex's getter things. Getter is just for getting data, you can't modify data with it.

Try to read the doc of the sortable lib: 
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#with-vuex

Comment: i changed a lot since this question, watch this blackmiaool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570391/sortable-array-not-updating-when-changing-position/45571410?noredirect=1#comment78104684_45571410