# sortable array not updating when changing position

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

i am using the dragable and sortable with vuejs, and i have a issue, everytime i change the position of two divs for example, they change but the json array doesn't update.

I am working with vuex, and i have in my component template this html:

```
<draggable v-model="myList">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" v-for="(value, key, index) in this.$store.getters.getDocumentAttributes">
        <div class="panel-body quote">
            <span @click="removeSection(index,key)" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-info"></span>
            <p>{{value.key}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</draggable>
```

then i got my computed prop that gets and sets the data that come from vuex,

```
computed: {
    sections() {
        return this.$store.getters.getDocument;
    },
    myList: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.getters.getDocument.getDocumentAttributes;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.$store.commit('updateList', value)
        }
    }

},
```

the updateList should update my list(if i am thinking well) so i have this:

```
},
mutations: {
      updateList: (state,list) => {
        state.Doc.atributes = list;
    }
},



document: { "id": "0", "atributes": [] },
```

i try to replace the old array with the new matching with the atributes array, any help with this?

ps: the document is inside the data, i just tried to place the necessary code.

Thanks

Comment: Could you have a little demo of what you have so far so we can see whats happening?

Comment: sorry atm i can't do that really wanted to, but i try to explain better

Comment: at the moment i can drag a div anc change positions between two divs, but they don't get updated on my json, my json doesn't refresh :/,

Comment: Could you provide me with the full set of code for the `new Vue({});`

Comment: i am using webpack simple the code is splited :/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup and got this to work by using `this.$forceUpdate()` in the computed property.

```
computed: {
  sections () {
    return this.$store.getters.getDocument;
  },
  myList: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.getters.getDocument.getDocumentAttributes;
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$forceUpdate()
      this.$store.commit('updateList', value)
    }
  }
},
```

**EDIT:**

I'm assuming you're also trying to directly dispatch a mutation since you don't have any actions listed, which is incorrect.

You should be **dispatching an action**, that **commits a mutation**... See below:

```
actions: {
  updateList: ({ commit }, list) {
    commit('updateList', list)
  }
},
mutations: {
  updateList: (state, list) => {
    state.Doc.atributes = list;
  }
},
```

Comment: what do you have on the updateList in the vuex side?

Comment: I have the equivalent of what you have.

Comment: ok, but my updateList never get called that is on of my problems :D

Comment: how is the set called?

Comment: my set is the problem, it never enters there